# How to save a variable to a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

This is my code:

```
set /p name=user save name
if %name%==[""]
cd c:\users\student\desktop\login system\usersXD
echo set "name=%name%"> %name%.bat
```

My code is not working. and i will like to load them up to view

Comment: What is _"is not working"_? What does it do or not do? What type input do you provide in the `set /p` entry? What do you expect it to do? You need to understand that you are also matching things thart makes no sence. `if %name%==[""]` will only match if your input is exactly `[""]` but then even if it did match, you do nothing after that on the same line. You also need to wrap paths in Double quotes, especially if they have whitespace. `cd "c:\users\student\desktop\login system\usersXD"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest following code for this task:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
goto PromptName

:ErrorInvalid
echo(
echo Error: The character !InvalidChar! is not allowed in name.
echo(
endlocal

:PromptName
set "Name="
set /P "Name=User save name: "
rem Has the user not input anything?
if not defined Name goto PromptName
rem Remove all double quotes from input string.
set "Name=%Name:"=%"
rem Has the user input just double quotes?
if not defined Name goto PromptName

rem Check if the input string contains any character not allowed in a file name.
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for %%I in ("<" ">" ":" "/" "\" "|") do if not "!Name:%%~I=!" == "!Name!" set "InvalidChar=%%~I" & goto ErrorInvalid
if not "!Name:?=!" == "!Name!" set "InvalidChar=?" & goto ErrorInvalid
if not "!Name:**=!" == "!Name!" set "InvalidChar=*" & goto ErrorInvalid
endlocal

cd /D "%UserProfile%\Desktop\login system\usersXD"
echo set "Name=%Name%">"%Name%.bat"
endlocal
```

The file name of the batch file to create must be enclosed in double quotes because it could contain a space or one of these characters `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~ `` which require enclosing the file name in double quotes.

This batch file should not be stored in directory `%UserProfile%\Desktop\login system\usersXD` on having file extension `.bat` as it could be overwritten during execution if the user enters a name the name of the batch file. It would be safe to have this batch file in that directory with file extension `.cmd`.

The batch file is still not 100% fail-safe despite the checks already added, but the user input string itself cannot result anymore in an exit of batch file execution because of a syntax error.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `cd /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

See also:

- Wikipedia article listing the predefined [Windows environment variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows) like `UserProfile`
- [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) explaining the operator `&`
- [How to stop Windows command interpreter from quitting batch file execution on an incorrect user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49834019/3074564)
- Microsoft documentation page [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) explaining the redirection operator `>`
- Microsoft documentation page [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file) listing which characters are not allowed in file/folder names

Answer (score 0):

This should work to save a variable in a bat file
If I remember

```
  (
  Echo set test=% 
  Echo set test=%test%
  Echo set test=%test%
  )>Test.bat
```